# Como pegar o modelo do iphone

Tags: swift, swift-3

Estou iniciando com *swift* e estou precisado pegar o modelo exato do *IPHONE* do cliente, já tentei o *UIDevice()* mas ele só me retorna *Iphone ou Ipad* e eu preciso saber se o aparelho é um *SE, 7, 8+, X,* etc.
Alguém sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Opa chegou a dar uma olhada nesta resposta?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model

Esta função parece retornar o que você precisa

```
    func modelIdentifier() -> String {
    if let simulatorModelIdentifier = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] { return simulatorModelIdentifier }
    var sysinfo = utsname()
    uname(&sysinfo) // ignore return value
    return String(bytes: Data(bytes: &sysinfo.machine, count: Int(_SYS_NAMELEN)), encoding: .ascii)!.trimmingCharacters(in: .controlCharacters)
}
```